# What is TaskTooLargeError in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am surprised to see this error (and not even documented in the quotas)...

Exceeding 100KB, I get this error:

```
TaskTooLargeError: Task size must be less than 102400
```

Any ideas on how to handle this?

The context: the body of emails (HTML) are being passed as arguments to a task queue.

Comment: It's not documented in the quotas because it's not a quota issue. However, the Task documentation says in various places that a Task is a "small unit of work", and a data payload is "a small amount of data for parameterizing the task". The limit on "small" is not defined in the docs, but you can read it in [the code](http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/r155/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py), and it's 100K, just as the error message says.

Comment: This document talks about using deferred lib for creating tasks.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred  and it does talk about limitations, task size, that task payload must be pickleable etc..  Worth a read.

Comment: The 100KB limit is documented in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Quotas_and_Limits_for_Push_Queues

Comment: @abarnert the code says 10K (maybe old version?)... MAX_TASK_SIZE_BYTES = 10 * (2 ** 10)

Comment: @bruno.braga: You're right, I clearly linked the wrong version. The fact that the error message is `Task size must be less than 102400` rather than `Task size must be less than 102400; found 12345678` is further evidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should store the body of the html  in the datastore and then pass the key of that entity to the task.

The same approach is taken if you have an instance of a Model that you want to pass to a task.  You normally pass the key of the entity, and the task can then fetch it.

Normally if I want to defer a method as a task I create a classmethod for an entity that takes the key as an argument, then it fetches the object, and then calls the actual method of the object.  The I can either call the method direct on the entity, or deferr things when needed.

e.g.

```
@classmethod
def defer_cancel_supervisor(cls,contract_key):

    contract = qtrack.models.Contract.get(db.Key(contract_key))
    contract.cancel_supervisor('contract cancelled')
```

Comment: My case is a bit simpler, so I am just moving all message body to the task itself, seems easier. But storing in DS to use it later looks like the good way to go. Cheers,

Comment: Watch out for memcache, remember things can be evicted at any time,and if your job fails and need to retry it may not have the payload still in memcache.